# Fields Combined

Tags: cognito-forms

In this new version, the first/last names and addresses are now all combined into one field on the export (name is all in one cell vs. first name in a field and last name in a field).  The entire address is now in one field too.

Is there a way to export the data automatically in separate fields like it used to be?

I'm having to manually separate everything out now to be able to make the new data usable with the old data.  What a pain!  I'm not a fan of this new change, so I really hope there's a way to go back to the old data file format.  The data was much easier to clean and sort when it was separated out in individual fields.

Comment: The name is in a column and the address is in another column.  They are not combined into one column; however, with the old data format, there were columns for the first name, last name, street address 1, street address 2, city, state and zip.  Now the first and last name are combined into one column and all the address parts are combined into another column.  I import new entries from the form into my existing data file.  I now have to break those columns into multiple columns to merge the data correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can still export your document the same way you could in the old entry view. When selecting the export option under 'Actions' you will want to select 'All Fields'. This will create an export with each field, and with part of a field in its own column.

[image]